# How to edit my query in order to calculate the difference between two numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to find the pageviews of my pages in the last 2 days

```
SELECT PAGE , COUNT( * ) AS poso, TIMESTAMP
FROM  `behaviour` 
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY PAGE , DATE( TIMESTAMP )
```

for example

```
+-----------------+--------+------------------------+
| PAGE            | poso   | TIMESTAMP              |
+-----------------+--------+------------------------+
| a page          | 6      | 2017-01-07 01:12:53    |
| a page          | 9      | 2017-01-08 01:06:19    |
+-----------------+--------+------------------------+
```

I am not interested in showing the results, but what I want to have (let's say in two columns) is all the `pages` and to calculate the pageview difference between each page. In the above example the  difference for `a page` is `3`.

How can I have this in a different column?

**UPDATE**

To answer the comment of Santi, I would like to use the most recent date minus the previous date to have the calculation. Also, the most recent date is the one that I want to include in the row.

At the end of the day, I will collect the 2 or 3 pages with the most positive difference.

Comment: As you're including the date here, you'd need to specify which two occurrences of `a page` you'd like to use - most recent minus oldest? Most recent minus second most recent? Additionally, if we're to rollup each page into a single row, which date would then be shown for that row? Please elaborate a bit here so we can provide you with the correct `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Comment: @Santi thank you for your suggestions. I have updated my question with the information asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT PAGE, COUNT( * ) AS poso,
       (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
        SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 
DAY))
       ) diff
FROM  `behaviour` 
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY PAGE;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. One question. Is there any way to have the row with the maximum and the row with the minimum difference?

Comment: @Pashiamas . . . Ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I have created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577414/how-to-get-the-10-max-and-10-min-of-rows-with-this-query