# How to get the 10 max and 10 min of rows with this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to find the difference in `pageviews` of my pages comparing the last 2 days

```
SELECT PAGE, COUNT( * ) AS poso,
       (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
        SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 
DAY))
       ) diff
FROM  `behaviour` 
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY PAGE;
```

The query returns me as pages as there are. However, what I want to do is to only have the 10 rows with the biggest positive difference, and the 10 withe th biggest negative difference.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **union** of two queries, one gets the **Top 10** and the other gets the **bottom 10**.  The query would look like this:

**Updated answer**

```
SELECT 
    PAGE
    , poso
    , diff
from
    (
        (
            SELECT PAGE, COUNT( * ) AS poso,
                (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
                    SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                ) diff
            FROM  `behaviour` 
            WHERE 
                DATE( TIMESTAMP ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
            GROUP BY PAGE
            ORDER BY (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
                        SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    ) desc
            LIMIT 10
        ) 
        UNION
        (   
            SELECT PAGE, COUNT( * ) AS poso,
                (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
                    SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                ) diff
            FROM  `behaviour` 
            WHERE 
                DATE( TIMESTAMP ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
            GROUP BY PAGE
            ORDER BY (SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = CURDATE()) - 
                        SUM(DATE(TIMESTAMP) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE( ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    ) asc
            LIMIT 10
        ) 
    ) as u
order by diff;
```

Comment: @Pashiamas -- My bad.  I did not actually have the DB tables so my first answer had some errors.  Please try the new one that I just posted.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: any way to modify this to find the difference between (yesterday+2 days ago+3 days ago ) - (4 + 5 + 6 days ago) ?

Comment: This probably would have to be done by rewriting your diff formula.  Please post a new question.